# Shell script to extract value for a variable from XML response

Tags: bash, shell, unix, xml-parsing

I have a XML response from which I need to extract the value of ObjDevice whenever the BillPlan="UBM - A/A". Can you please help me with a shell script to do the same

```
    <Txn>
            <TxnName>Spectrum-AlertSite-Component_spectrum.engprod_InstantUpgradeEdge_GetProductOffersByAccount_getProductOffersByAccountValid</TxnName>
            <TxnDetail Monitor="y" Notify="y" PingError="n"
  TraceError="y" Interval="5" TimeOut="300"
  ObjDevice="318373" BillPlan="UBM - A/A" MaxSteps="50"

 />
        </Txn>
        <Txn>
            <TxnName>Spectrum-AlertSite-Component_spectrum.engprod_InstantUpgradeEdge_GetProductOffersByAccount_getProductOffersByAccountValid</TxnName>
            <TxnDetail Monitor="y" Notify="y" PingError="n"
  TraceError="y" Interval="5" TimeOut="300"
  ObjDevice="318377" BillPlan="UBM - A/A" MaxSteps="50"

 />
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of the other "how do I extract a value from an XML document in shell" questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you don't have a special tool to handle XML files and you always have in the same line both values then you can execute:

```
grep 'BillPlan="UBM - A/A"' | sed 's,.*ObjDevice="\([0-9]*\)" BillPlan="UBM - A/A".*,\1,"
```

Sorry if I don't use sed to filter  but not so familiar with sed and also don't have access to a *nix, but maybe somebody else can give us the short version

Comment: In your `sed` command you should start with a `s` or combine it to `sed -ne '/BillPlan="UBM - A\/A"/s,.*ObjDevice="\([0-9]*\)" BillPlan="UBM - A/A".*,\1,p'`

Answer (score 1):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//TxnDetail[@BillPlan="UBM - A/A"]' \
                  -v ./@ObjDevice -n \
  <in.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

With my [Xidel](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html) you can do:

```
xidel /tmp/foo.xml -e '//TxnDetail[@BillPlan="UBM - A/A"]/@ObjDevice'
```

Answer (score 1):

I asume `libxml2` is installed (quite likely on any GNU/Linux system):

```
xmllint --xpath '//TxnDetail[@BillPlan="UBM - A/A"]/@ObjDevice' input.xml
```